# Zero downtime and auto restart of nodejs server

Tags: node.js, pm2, nodemon

I am working to implement the Nodejs based application and I want to zero downtime and auto deployment on file change. In summary I have following requirements.

1. On Node process crash, it should restart itself On any file change
   it should restart itself to do the deployment
2. On system reboot, Node server should restart itself
3. If memory or cpu consumption is more than defined value then Node server should restart itself.
4. When server image is created from already installed server and create new server out of this then in new server as well it should have same settings
5. In case Nodejs server get shutdown signal then it should shutdown gracefully, i.e. it should stop accepting any new connection and it should first finish existing request and then should be shutdown

Please help.

Comment: Can you please ask a specific question?  A list of requirements of things you might like to have in your deployed solution is not a specific question.  It might work better here on StackOverflow if you pick one of your items and ask how you would implement that particular item.

Comment: Thanks, I thought to keep all problem at one place so that consolidated solution can  be fine. Let me post each specific separately.